# The sessionStorage doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

The code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', ["$window"]);
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
            $scope.Save = function () {
                $window.sessionStorage.setItem("app1", "SessionStorage: My name is Mudassar Khan.");
            }
            $scope.Get = function () {
                $window.alert("OK");
                $window.alert($window.sessionStorage.getItem("app1"));
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="Save()" />
        <input type="button" value="Get" ng-click="Get()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It happens nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular checks for window dependency and it fails. So remove it from `module` and include only in `controller`.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
```

Answer (score 0):

When declaring your module, you have passed `$window` as a dependency to it.
Angular sees it as an external module and tries to locate it, then you get this exception:

`Module '$window' is not available!`

`$window` is not a module, it is an angular wrapper for `window` object.

Try this:

`var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);`